# Correlation matrix using opencl

Tags: opencl, pyopencl, pearson-correlation

How can we efficiently implement calculation of correlation matrix (pearson correlation) using opencl? Can anyone help me with the kernel function?

Comment: Please remember the guidelines. {How-to-ask)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. What have you tried?